# Sharing contact list between SharePoint & Outlook

Tags: list, document-library, office-365

I have created a contact list in SharePoint and successfully linked it to Outlook using the connect to Outlook button in SharePoint. I can see all the records under other contacts, which is fine.

However. How do I link the view to Outlook, if I create a view on my contact list in SharePoint?